# How can a program on Linux introspect its pid?

Tags: linux, introspection

How can a program on Linux discover the process id of itself?  Is there something in /proc/self that will do the trick?

Comment: btw, since you've cited /proc/self, dig into the /proc/self/task "directory", you'll see one or more dirs, and you can guess what they are. (try exploring it from the shell using a specific pid, e.g. `ls /proc/X/task`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`getpid(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid).

Answer (score 4):

Try running on your terminal:
man getpid